# Adding Multiple PushPin to Bing Map control (XAML & C#) in WINRT

Tags: windows-runtime, bing-maps, winrt-xaml

How i can add  multiple push pins to bing map control. In my application, i tried to add some user control(Push pins) as children of that map control. But the issue is that when i performing zoom -in and zoom-out operation the push pin moves around the map and miss places the position.
Here is the code i used for adding multiple push pins to the map :

```
            foreach (var item in PushPinCollection)
            {
                    var pin = new CustomMapPin(Convert.ToInt32(item.BackgroundColorID)) { Name = item.ID.ToString() };
                    pin.DoubleTapped += PushpinTapped1;
                     pin.Tapped += PinTapped;
                     var loc = new Location(Convert.ToDouble(item.Latitude, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), Convert.ToDouble(item.Longitude, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                     pin.SetValue(MapLayer.PositionProperty, loc);
                     NoteMap.Children.Add(pin);
                }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
            Bing.Maps.Location loc = new Bing.Maps.Location
            {
                Latitude = latitude,
                Longitude = longitude
            };

            myMap.SetView(loc, 13);

            Pushpin pushpin = new Pushpin();
            pushpin.Tapped +=pushpin_Tapped;

            pushpin.Text = address;
            MapLayer.SetPosition(pushpin, loc);
            myMap.Children.Add(pushpin);
```

Comment: Side question - is there an *easy* way to make a pushpin draggable?